# Dynamically create accordion in a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a set of dynamic expand/collapse list. I am making use of bootstrap angularjs uib-accordion to achieve this. This is what I want to achieve.

```
<p>
    <uib-accordion>
        <uib-accordion-group>
          <uib-accordion-heading>
            <a href="data">I can have markup, too!</a>
          </uib-accordion-heading>
          This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
        </uib-accordion-group>
        <uib-accordion-group>
          <uib-accordion-heading>
            <a href="data">I can have markup, too! </a>
          </uib-accordion-heading>
          This is just some content.
        </uib-accordion-group>
  </uib-accordion>
</p>
```

Here the uib-accordian-group has to be created dynamically in a directive.
This is what I have done.

myHtml

```
<p><my-directive></my-directive></p>
```

myDirective.js

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($compile){
        return {
            'restrict': 'E',
            template:'<uib-accordion name="topElement" close-others=true ></uib-accordion>',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                var myList = { //populated dynamically
                    {
                            "title": "link to click",
                            "category": "my category" 
                        }, {
                            "title": "link to click"
                            "category": "data to show on expand" 
                        },
                }

                for(var index = 0; index < myList.length; index++) { 
                    var group = angular.element("<uib-accordion-group>");

                    var linkFormed = angular.element("<a>");
                    linkFormed.attr("text", myList[index].title)
                    linkFormed.attr("href", myList[index].title)
                    linkFormed.attr("title", myList[index].title)

                    var heading = angular.element("<uib-accordion-heading/>");
                    heading.append(linkFormed);

                    group.append(myList[index].category);
                    group.append(heading);

                    $element.find("[name='topElement']").append(group); 
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But when I run this code my html is rendered as shown below

```
<my-directive>
   <uib-accordion name="dialogData" close-others="true">
      <div class="panel-group" ng-transclude=""></div>
   </uib-accordion>
</my-directive>
```

I tried `$compile(group)($scope)` before appending it to `$element` but it gives this error.

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'uibAccordion', required by
>   directive 'uibAccordionGroup', can't be found!

I am not sure what the problem is. Could someone please let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Couldn't you forego the directive and just handle it with an ng-repeat?

Comment: No, this has to be a part of my directive.

Comment: Ok.  What is myUtil.myList?  I don't see where myUtil is declared or injected.  Seems like myList would be an attribute on your directive.

Comment: Its some data populated dynamically. Please check my edit. I have populated myList

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this.  You're dealing with 3 levels of accordion directives (accordion, accordion-group, accordion-header) where the last 2 require the parent directive and their respective controller to already exist and they don't.  Nesting elements in a directive like this is fine but these aren't elements, they are directives.